# Regarding functions in C

Tags: c, function

I am a beginner in c programming. I am working on some open source code and saw this:

```
function_name(parameters) SOME_OTHER_THING(some_variable_as_parameter) {
  //some code
}
```

I don't know what this is and for the lack of my knowledge cannot ask the question in a better way. Sorry. Can someone please tell what this is? (Even if you saw something similar to it, you can mention it.)

Thank you.

Exact function is:

```
void ofproto_rule_delete(struct ofproto *ofproto, struct rule *rule)
    OVS_EXCLUDED(ofproto_mutex)
{
    //some more code
}
```

Comment: You may get an answer, but the best thing to do might be to start with a good C tutorial.

Comment: `THINGS_IN_CAPS` are usually macros and `MACROS_THAT_LOOKS_LIKE_FUNCTIONS()` are macros that accept arguments

Comment: but how can you call something after the parameter list of a function

Comment: I have read some 2-3 books on C programming and never saw something like this.

Comment: It's a macro which expands to an \_\_attribute\_\_ for the function: https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/0692257923fed2ecd56906a5c06c9426f7e62463/include/openvswitch/compiler.h#L136

Comment: Macros don't get called. They are processed BEFORE the compiler compiles the code. What macros do is something like cut-and-paste text into your source code before the code gets compiled. Some compilers can dump source after macro expansion but before compilation. If your compiler can do that try it

Answer (score 4):

That's a macro which gets expanded by the compiler before the code is compiled. In this case, the macro [can be found here](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/0692257923fed2ecd56906a5c06c9426f7e62463/include/openvswitch/compiler.h#L136) (at least for Clang):

```
#define OVS_EXCLUDED(...) __attribute__((locks_excluded(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

This tells the compiler to replace `OVS_EXCLUDED(ofproto_mutex)` in the code with `__attribute__((locks_excluded(__VA_ARGS__)))` before compiling the code. The `__VA_ARGS__` tells the compiler to paste whatever is passed to the macro (the `...`, which is `ofproto_mutex` in this case). Thus the final result would look something like this:

```
void ofproto_rule_delete(struct ofproto *ofproto, struct rule *rule)
    __attribute__((locks_excluded(ofproto_mutex)))
{
    //some more code
}
```

Note that, because of the `#ifdef` rules in that file, for non-Clang compilers the macro will be defined as:

```
#define OVS_EXCLUDED(...)
```

Which will just expand to nothing, leaving just the function as you'd expect it:

```
void ofproto_rule_delete(struct ofproto *ofproto, struct rule *rule)
{
    //some more code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is thread safety annotation provided as attribute to the function, Which declares that the caller must not hold the given lock. This annotation is used to prevent deadlock. Many mutex implementations are not re-entrant, so deadlock can occur if the function acquires the mutex a second time.

Reference:

[Declaring Attributes of Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

[Clang Thread Safety Analysis](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html)